# Bootstrap - aligning figures with col-sm-4 command

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align horizontaly three elements using the col-sm-4 function but for whatever reason I am missing it is not working. No matter what I do, the items are still displayed aligned to left and vertically. The images are all the same size.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<section class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-sm-4">
          <p text-align: center>PLAY</p>
          <img src="img/m1.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-4">
          <p text-align: center>LEARN</p>
          <img src="img/m2.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-4">
          <p text-align: center>HELP</p>
          <img src="img/m3.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </section>
```

and the css:

```
section .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px dotted #000;
  clear: none;
  }
```

It puzzles me because I have looked over other websites using the same technique and I cannot spot the error. Thanks.

Comment: have you included the bootstrap library? otherwise your css classes wont do anything because they are not defined.

Comment: inline style should define like <p style="text-align: center">

Comment: please add this to your head <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: i think you are not include the bootstrap css, because `.col-` classes have default `float:left` property

Comment: Isn't this a bootstrap library?  <link rel="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

you want like this ?

```
section .row img {

  border: 4px dotted #000;
  clear: none;
  display:inline-block;
  }
  .col-sm-4
  {
    display:inline-block;

  }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/0nd7zz0m/)

Comment: Yes. That's the expected result. Yet, even with your css code it is still not working to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

After making a few adjustments, I managed to get your code working (see comments in snippet for details)

```css
/* made the boxes use flexible boxes to lay themselves out in a row */

.flexgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
 
}
/* fixed css because there were no 'row' elemeents */

/* added the > operand */

section > .col > img {
  margin: 30px 0 30px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 4px dotted #000;
  clear: none;
  align: center;
}
.col > div, .col > img {
  content-align: center
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="flexgrid">
    <figure class="col">

      <!-- change <p> to <div>  to avoid newline -->
      <div>PLAY</div>
      <center>
      <img src="img/m1.jpg" />
       </center>
    </figure>
    <figure class="col">
      <div>LEARN</div>
      <center>
      <img src="img/m2.jpg" />
       </center>
    </figure>
    <figure class="col">
      <div>HELP</div>
      <center>
      <img src="img/m3.jpg" />
        </center>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the screen size your using not being specified in the col-*-* format. I've added `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` as the class to support all screen sizes and it is working perfectly now.

```css
section .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px dotted #000;
  clear: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>PLAY</p>
          <img src="img/m1.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>LEARN</p>
          <img src="img/m2.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>HELP</p>
          <img src="img/m3.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked best. Thank you. However it generated other issues.
1. Introducing the library has override my own css changing the display style of other elements on page. Ex: Buttons.
2. The elements are now apparently confined into a container that is smaller than the rest of the containers on the page which stretch for the whole width of the page making all the other elements look out of alignment.

Comment: 1. Just include your css after the bootstrap css file. it should override the bootstrap styling. 2. Just change the container widths and column widths to fix the alignment issues.

Comment: I did that. My css link is last just before the </head>. Bootstrap css still overrides. :(

Comment: you can put '!important' for any overridden css stylings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use predefined bootstrap class `text-center` for `<div class=row...`:

```css
section .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px dotted #000;
  clear: none;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <figure class="col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>PLAY</p>
          <img src="img/m1.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>LEARN</p>
          <img src="img/m2.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-xs-4">
          <p text-align: center>HELP</p>
          <img src="img/m3.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </section>
```